# Help in Matlab Laplace Equation

Tags: matlab

I have tried to implement Laplace equation in my matlab code sequence as shown below. I created this LaplaceExplicit.m and thus used another function numgrid in the same. However, it shows error as "Input variable n is undefined". What should be done? The code is as below-

```
    function [x,y,T]= LaplaceExplicit(n,m,Dx,Dy)
    echo off;
    numgrid(n,m);
    R = 5.0;
    T = R*ones(n+1,m+1); % All T(i,j) = 1 includes all boundary conditions
    x = [0:Dx:n*Dx];y=[0:Dy:m*Dy]; % x and y vectors
    for i = 1:n % Boundary conditions at j = m+1 and j = 1
    6
    T(i,m+1) = T(i,m+1)+ R*x(i)*(1-x(i));
    T(i,1) = T(i,1) + R*x(i)*(x(i)-1);
    end;
    TN = T; % TN = new iteration for solution
    err = TN-T;
    % Parameters in the solution
    beta = Dx/Dy;
    denom = 2*(1+beta^2);
    % Iterative procedure
    epsilon = 1e-5; % tolerance for convergence
    imax = 1000; % maximum number of iterations allowed
    k = 1; % initial index value for iteration
    % Calculation loop
    while k<= imax
    for i = 2:n
    for j = 2:m
    TN(i,j)=(T(i-1,j)+T(i+1,j)+beta^2*(T(i,j-1)+T(i,j+1)))/denom;
    err(i,j) = abs(TN(i,j)-T(i,j));
    end;
    end;
    T = TN; k = k + 1;
    errmax = max(max(err));
    if errmax < epsilon
    [X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
    figure(2);contour(X,Y,T',20);xlabel('x');ylabel('y');
    title('Laplace equation solution - Dirichlet boundary conditions Explicit');
    figure(3);surfc(X,Y,T');xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('T(x,y)');
    title('Laplace equation solution - Dirichlet boundary conditions Explicit');
    fprintf('Convergence achieved after %i iterations.\n',k);
    fprintf('See the following figures:\n');
    fprintf('==========================\n');
    fprintf('Figure 1 - sketch of computational grid \n');
    fprintf('Figure 2 - contour plot of temperature \n');
    fprintf('Figure 3 - surface plot of temperature \n');
    return
    end;
    end;
    fprintf('\n No convergence after %i iterations.',k);
```

Comment: how are you using the function? can you give an example of the inputs n,m,Dx,Dy?

Comment: Also it seems that the `numgrid` line is missing a variable assignment. One would expect something like: `g = numgrid(n,m)` ...

Comment: NUMGRID Number the grid points in a two dimensional region.
   G = NUMGRID(REGION,N) numbers the points on an N-by-N grid in
   the subregion of -1<=x<=1 and -1<=y<=1 determined by REGION.
   SPY(NUMGRID(REGION,N)) plots the points.
   DELSQ(NUMGRID(REGION,N)) generates the 5-point discrete Laplacian.

Comment: you haven't answer my first question, what are `n,m,Dx,Dy` ?

Comment: if we have a rectangular domain of L=5 cm, H= 3.5 cm, with increment in x, Dx=1cm and in y, Dy=0.5cm. n is L/Dx while m is H/Dy. In other words, n and m are no of sub-intervals while Dx, Dy are step size

Comment: @Akshay Would it be possible to have all the line codes so that I could run it and help solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB will go through a standard look-up procedure to work out what it represents. First, is it a local variable? If not, is a function or script (command)? This also requires looking in a prescribed set of places. The simple version is: first look in the current directory, then look in the directories specified by the MATLAB path (in order).

Hence, if you write square_table.m and save it in C:\work\Moe\MATLAB then that directory needs to be either the current working directory on on the MATLAB path. Otherwise you will get an error ("undefined function or variable").

Answer (score 0):

Sorry people, got my questions answered.. it was just some problem with initialisation and calling a function defined in another .m file. Resolved it and now the code's working fine.. :)